# what does mean the command if(0) in r?

Tags: r

I have a question, I have been reviewing some code and in one script, the authors use:

```
if(0){
    #do something
}
```

Any help in what `if(0)` means?

Comment: Could be just a placeholder for a *real* if statement.

Comment: That it’s bad code. ;-)

Comment: What will be a better practice? I have seen this a lot of times. I thought this is usual...@Konrad Rudolph

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The author (most likely) put the block of code in an if statement so that they could easily remove it if necessary without having to comment it out (or remove it).  Similar to if(true) or if(false), you just need to change one value and it would skip that code.

Upon reviewing the code, developers should remove these kinds of statements once they've finalized all their source code not to confuse others.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something that will never be executed, since 0 = FALSE. Most probably this is a manual switch to test some code in parenthesis.